# Does Mössbauer effect have a minimum requirement on the hardness of solid materials?

Tags: solid-state-physics, nuclear-physics, gamma-rays

Mössbauer effect is a recoilless absorption and reemission of gamma photons in solid materials. Although atomic nuclei are very heavy, because the momentum of gamma photons is very large, the recoil and kinetic energy transfer of single atoms (in gas or liquid phases) is still non-negligible. However in solid materials atoms are tightly bound together, which enables atoms to transfer momentum among each other. As a result, the momentum is absorbed by the crystal lattice as a whole instead of single atoms, which results in undetectable energy loss of the reemission.

However, not all solid materials are tightly bound together. Some materials are tightly bound together by covalent (diamonds), ionic (sapphires) or metallic (iron and tungsten) bonds, which results in their high melting points and mechanical strengths. Other solid materials (sulfur and phosphor) are only loosely bound together by the weak Van der Waals forces between molecules, which results in their low melting points and hardness. Among them high-oxidation fluorides bind most weakly with each other. The reason is that these molecules are perfectly symmetrical, which results in zero permanent dipole moments. Fluorine atoms also have an extremely low polarizability comparable with hydrogen atoms, which makes the interaction between molecules comparable with noble gases. As a result, many fluoride compounds like SF6, WF6 and UF6 have disproportionately low melting points and boiling points regarding their molecular weights. If we can synthesize low melting point fluorides of Mössbauer active elements, will we be able to observe Mössbauer effect in these materials?